# is there a code that can fix my current code?

Tags: excel, checkout, checkin

I've created a check-in / check-out system. my code works perfectly fine when applied to only one sheet. but when I try to apply this code to multiple sheets, I get error, I've tried three codes and still cant get excel to apply the code to each separate sheet. Any code I use, confuses excel and redirects me to the first sheet.

1st code I used

```
dim WS as worksheet
for each WS in sheets
(my code)
next WS
```

2nd code I used

```
For Each Worksheet In ThisWorkbook.worksheets
sheets("may","June","july").activate
(my code)
next worksheet
```

ive also tried, (worksheet.activate) but this code redirects me to the first sheet and losses the data on other sheets

Here's the current code I'm trying to get to work

```
Sub Check_in()
For Each Worksheet In ThisWorkbook.worksheets
worksheets("April", "May", "June").Activate
Dim code As String: code = InputBox("Please scan a barcode", "Scan    procedure")
If code = "" Then MsgBox ("No code scanned"): Exit Sub
Dim NbChIn As Integer: NbChIn = application.CountIf(Range("STORE_RECORDS [CHECKED OUT on its way to analytical lab]"), code)
Dim NbChOut As Integer: NbChOut = application.CountIf(Range("STORE_RECORDS[SAMPLE RECEIVED from analytical lab]"), code)


If NbChIn > NbChOut And NbChIn > 0 Then
MsgBox ("This sample is already Checked-out" & Chr(10) & "Please click  sample received and retry"): Exit Sub
Else
Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0) = code
Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(0, 1) = Now
End If
Next Worksheet
End Sub

Sub Check_Out()
Dim code As String: code = InputBox("Please scan a barcode", "Scan procedure")
If code = "" Then MsgBox ("No code scanned"): Exit Sub
Dim NbChIn As Integer: NbChIn = application.CountIf(Range("STORE_RECORDS[CHECKED OUT on its way to analytical lab]"), code)
Dim NbChOut As Integer: NbChOut = application.CountIf(Range("STORE_RECORDS[SAMPLE RECEIVED from analytical lab]"), code)
If NbChIn = NbChOut And NbChIn > 0 Then
    MsgBox ("This sample has already been received" & Chr(10) & "Please check it out and retry"): Exit Sub
Else
    If Range("STORE_RECORDS[CHECKED OUT on its way to analytical lab]").Find(code, , , xlWhole, , xlPrevious) Is Nothing Then MsgBox ("No match, ask Carlos !"): Exit Sub
    Range("STORE_RECORDS[CHECKED OUT on its way to analytical lab]").Find(code, , , xlWhole, , xlPrevious).Offset(0, 2) = code
    Range("STORE_RECORDS[CHECKED OUT on its way to analytical lab]").Find(code, , , xlWhole, , xlPrevious).Offset(0, 3) = Now
End If
End Sub'
```

code usually says wrong number of arguments, or object doesn't support this property or method. code only works on sheet 1 or in my case (April) I want this code to apply to each sheet, organized by months.

Comment: I would recommend extracting the code (that should be applied to each sheet) out into a separate sub with a worksheet parameter. Inside the sub, make sure all ranges are fully qualified (i.e. `worksheetVar.Range("A1")` instead of `Range("A1")`). Then, when cycling through worksheets, check if the worksheet is one that should have the code "applied" (probably through a name or codename check), then call the custom sub, passing in that worksheet.

Comment: Also, I would not recommend using `.Select`. If that's required to make the code functional, there's at least one Range (or other sheet-specific object) reference that isn't fully qualified.

Comment: sorry for the late reply. this helped thank you